# databinding issue when trying to Eval

Tags: c#

code:

```
 <uc1:UploadImageControl ID="UploadImageControl1" runat="server" SaveButtonID="btnUpdate"
                                     ImageDirectory="centers" ImageFileName='center_<#Eval("CENTER_ID")%>' DeleteImageAfterSave="true"
                                      MaxUploadSize="5000000" />
```

the result from `center_<#Eval("CENTER_ID")%>` is always `center_<#Eval("CENTER_ID")%>` my question is why the eval don't give me the right centre id who should be `31`

Comment: You are missing the opening % ;)

Answer (score 0):

% before # is missing:

ImageFileName='center_<%#Eval("CENTER_ID")%>'

Answer (score 0):

You are missing % before #, try this

```
ImageFileName='center_<%#Eval("CENTER_ID")%>'
```

instead of

```
ImageFileName='center_<#Eval("CENTER_ID")%>'
```

Comment: i fixed it but still the same thing :/